# Solving 2D FDM Laplace with mixed boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem

I am trying to solve $\Delta u = 0$ in a rectangular 2D domain with non-uniform spacing (i.e $dx \ne dy$). Dirichlet boundary conditions are set on the eastern and western faces and Neumann boundary conditions are set on the northern and southern faces.

I am trying to use a direct method ($Au = b$) however I am struggling with setting up the matrix and stencils given the mixed conditions and non-square mesh.

Therefore I have 2 questions:

1. What would the matrix $A$ look like and how could I create it programatically?
2. What rows in $u$ may I cut out and how should that vector look like given my boundary conditions?